# Array balancing

Tags: arrays, math

we have two arrays a[] and b[] and we need to find minimum absolute difference between sum of two arrays a & b and minimum no. of moves to make minimum absolute difference.

> Example :
>  a[ ] = {70,30,33,23,4,4,34,95} sum = 293
> b[ ] = {50,10,10,7} sum = 77
>
> move 95,23 from array a to b.
> move 10 from array a to b

after moving both the array's sum becomes 185

output is 0 , 3 (difference between two arrays , no. of moves)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No. I dont have any idea.

Comment: another example is : a[] = {50,45,13}, b[] = {23,32,45} o/p is 2,2 move 50 from a[] and 45 from b[]

Comment: What would you choose if one variant gives diff. 1 with 2 moves, another variant gives diff. 2 and 1 move?

Comment: diff 1 with 2 moves. the diff should be minimum and do minimum no. of movs to get minimum value. if diff. 3 with 2 moves and diff 3 with 3 moves means choose diff 3 with 2moves

Comment: Small hint: 293+77 ==185+185... So if you add all sums together, and devide IT by 2, you would know which number you need. With backtracking you can find out very fast which Numbers you want to change.

Comment: Small gibt: 293+77 ==185+185... So if you add all sums together, and devide IT by 2, you would know which number you need. With backtracking you can find out very fast which Numbers you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your problem, "find minimum absolute difference between sum of two arrays a & b", is a variation of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Wikipedia defines that as "Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible."

To see this, combine all the values in `a` and in `b` into a new array `ab` and find half the sum of its values. You want to find elements in `ab` that sum to that half-sum, or as close to it as possible. You could then place those values and `a` and the rest in `b`, and that is one of the ways to get the minimum absolute difference.

To find your "minimum number of moves" we could find *all* the ways to solve the knapsack problem, then for each solution find how many moves it would take to get back to the original `a` and `b` (or the original `b` and `a` if that takes fewer moves).

The [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity) of just the first part of your problem is famously NP-complete, so expect a long-running program for any sizable arrays. The Wikipedia article has a variety of algorithms to solve that first part of your problem, so you can start there and make a choice of algorithms.

No wonder this is a competitive-programming problem!